# Does the java world have a task queue similar to celery?

Tags: java, queue, celery

Seeing as java is so mature, I'm hoping someone can tell me if java has something similar to http://celeryproject.org/

It is a distributed task queue.

I'm writing to rabbitmq, and want to know what options there are other than celery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems [Octobot](http://octobot.taco.cat) would be something you should look into. Haven't used it though.

Answer (score 2):

Does using Celery through [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) work for you?  Jython is cited as working with Celery so you might be able to use the best of both worlds there.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Scheduler has support for clustering - you can run Quartz on multiple machines as a single entity. However it relies on database persistence for receiving new jobs, not sure how easy or hard it is to integrate with RabbitMQ - although you could always write a small glue app to pick up messages from the RabbitMQ and create new Quartz jobs from it.